# Deferred 'lazy' loading of YouTube video content and SEO effect

Tags: seo, load, lazy-evaluation

My site uses a fair amount of plugins / active content from YouTube videos, Facebook and SoundCloud.  The effect of these adds a fair amount to the load time of the page.

I developed code which populates a DIV with the embedded Iframe after the page is loaded, using the Jquery .ready() event.  It is nothing clever, but it makes a big improvement to the page load time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#video").html("<iframe width='350' height='230' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/myid?wmode=transparent' frameborder='0'></iframe> ");
});

</script>
```

From an SEO point of view, Google likes video content as long as it relates to the page content.  My code relies on Javascript to load the video after the page has loaded.  I know the Googlebot uses Javascript, but is this method safe to use and will it affect my SEO?

Answer (score 1):

In general Google won't index stuff rendered with JS. The code for your video is fine since it helps to reduce page load time.

You can try including content that is relevant to the video within the #video element. This will help provide some SEO context around your video and help anyone without JS turned on.